# how to modify and apply styles across the document for specific paragraphs?

Tags: excel, vba

I have word document with different styles like heading1, heading2, normal, bodytext etc. I'm trying to write a VBA macro which will first modify the styles as per requirement and then apply those styles across the document accordingly. See below, I'm changing the font size first for style=normal and heding1 and then want to apply it for all paragraphs where style=normal is already defined. So it will update the style for existing heading1 and normal separately.

NOTE: I want to do it with style only. I can do it using for loop by going each paragraph one by one and then find what is the style of that paragraph and then apply the style accordingly AND it is working perfectly if I do in this way but in my document I have 60000 paragraphs and so it is taking long time like 10 hours. So, Im looking for a way to do it for each different styles in one shot. Please let me know if there is any way to do it.

```
ActiveDocument.Styles(wdStyleNormal).Font.Name = "Arial"
ActiveDocument.Styles(wdStyleNormal).Font.Size = 12

ActiveDocument.Styles(wdStyleHeading1).Font.Name = "Arial"
ActiveDocument.Styles(wdStyleHeading1).Font.Size = 20

ActiveDocument.UpdateStyles
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried and ended up with this solution. I hope it will work for you.

```
Sub ChangeStyle()
    With ActiveDocument.Styles("wdStyleNormal").Font
        .Color = wdColorAqua 'wdColorRed
        .Name = "Arial"
        .Size = 12
    End With
    With ActiveDocument.Styles("wdStyleNormal")
        .AutomaticallyUpdate = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for sharing it. I think wdStyleNormal should not be within the quotation in your code. Now coming to the main problem. I tried this code earlier. But the problem is lets say in a paragraph you have two different font size. then it will not change both the font size at 12. Just have two different font size in a single paragraph in you word doc and run this. You will see it.

Comment: I think the solution can be to reset all the fonts to the one of the style by using the ActiveDocument.Range.Font.Reset. After it should work.

Comment: How to select range for different styles separately?